# How to work with DispatchQueue.global?

Tags: swift3

I am downloading images from my server using this

```
let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)
    queue.async{ ...
```

And while images downloading user can tap the button. But sometimes this button doesn't work (when all images done button work correct). 
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Donot access global queue for that, instead create a custom `DispatchQueue` with label, qos as `.background` and fetch the image, when done use `DispatchQueue.main` to return the image to the main queue

For e.g:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "myImageQueue", qos: .background)
queue.async {
      ...fetch image
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.imageView.image = fetchedImage
      }
}
```